# Remove only one class from a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to remove only selectedchildren class using Jquery?

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="children selectedchildren"></div>
<div class="children"></div>
<div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to delete the div or only the class ...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to focus on just `class="parent"` `<div>`:

`.eq()` is the child selector and;

`.removeClass()` remove the a desired class from that element

```
$('.parent').eq(1).removeClass('selectedchildren');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectedchildren').removeClass('selectedchildren');
```

This will remove the class from all 'selectedchildren' elements. If you need to make sure it's just the first, then you can do

```
$($('.selectedchildren')[0]).removeClass('selectedchildren');
```

Comment: why use `$($())` when there are numerous more readable ways to target first one using selectors and methods?

Comment: I like the array syntax. But you're right. I believe .first() will return the first element as a jqeury element. Is that correct?